# How to set custom bookmark icons with Gio?

Tags: nautilus, icons, bookmarks

I'm building a custom live CD with Cubic

I want to add a default customized folder on $HOME, "Projects"

**What I did:**

- Edit /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults
- Add a line `PROJECTS=Projects`

**Result:**

- The folder "Projects" (with localized translation) is added on $HOME

Now I want 2 things:

- Add this folder to favorites (but how to add it on favorites by default ? Editing /etc/skel/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks ? No risk to be reset after image installation ?)
- Add folder and bookmark icon

For the icons, I know I can add an emblem ; but it doesn't update bookmark icon. Is there a way to modify the gio attributes `standard::icon` and `standard::symbolic-icon` ?

I already have custom icons created on /usr/share/icons folder

I can add gio attribute `metadata::custom-icon`, but it uses absolute link and not an optimized icon resolution like with a theme. I could be OK as a fallback, but how to do the same thing for bookmark icon ?

Thanks !

Comment: Suggestion for your 1st part, in the "What I did" section: You should probably just create an empty `Projects` folder in `/etc/skel/`. This is because `user-dirs.defaults` only supports eight possible names (DESKTOP, DOWNLOAD, TEMPLATES, PUBLICSHARE, DOCUMENTS, MUSIC, PICTURES, and VIDEOS). Even though it works to create an empty folder in the user's home directory, it is probably not the right way to do it. (See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/user-dirs.defaults.5.html).

Comment: Oh no, it works with any values, and the folder is created :) Only problem is, icon customization. But I found the C sources and saw that it's hardcoded, so there is no way to do it with custom folder, I had to use existing one (like XDG_PUBLIC) to change default icon :/

Comment: Doubidou, that's fine. My point is that skel should probably be used as the mechanism to create new user folders, rather than user-dirs.defaults, because the documentation indicates only eight folders types are officially supported. It probably works because of a bug in the code that simply creates a folder when an unsupported folder type is encountered in the configuration. Nevertheless, if it works for you and you are happy with it, then that is fine. I didn't mean to derail your question.

Comment: Regarding your original question, I have not come across a solution, and all of the documentation I've come across indicated that this is hard coded into Nautilus. I've bookmarked this question, so if I ever come across a fix, I will be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

> I can add gio attribute `metadata::custom-icon`, but it uses absolute link and not an optimized icon resolution like with a theme.

Actually, you *can* set a named, themed icon too: just use `metadata::custom-icon-name` instead of `metadata::custom-icon`!

```sh
gio set "$(xdg-user-dir PROJECTS)" "metadata::custom-icon-name" folder-system
```

You must also *delete* any existing `metadata::custom-icon` that might be already set, as it takes precedence over `metadata::custom-icon-name`:

```sh
gio set --delete PATH "metadata::custom-icon"
```

(or `gio set --type=unset ...` in older Gio versions)

---

> Add this folder to favorites (but how to add it on favorites by default ? Editing /etc/skel/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks ? No risk to be reset after image installation ?)

Technically this is a *bookmark*, not a *favorite*. In Gnome parlance, a **Favorite** is an "app" (a `.desktop` file) that is *pinned* to your *launcher* bar, while a **Bookmark** is a path (directory) shown in places like the Nautilus side-panel and Open File dialogs. Not to be confused with a **Star**, which is a starred path (directory or file) that you can access via "Starred" meta-folder (similar to "Recents").

That said, yes, `/etc/skel/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` is a suitable place to pre-populate custom bookmarks.